# What's the fastest way to register a java-application (or maybe a bat executing the app) as a Windows service?

Tags: java, windows, service

What's the fastest way to register a java-application (or maybe a bat executing the app) as a Windows service?

Update 1: It has to be free for companies to execute :)

Either by using a third party app or following a guide.

Answer (score 1):

I recently tried a bunch and had most luck with [Java service wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp) There is a cummunity edition which is gpl as well as commercially supported versions

Comment: we also use JSW in our products as well. It is available as both 32-bit (free) and 64-bit (not free) versions.

Comment: Faisal, is the 32bit version usable on 64bit windows?